# Insert sequential code from select

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, insert, auto

I'm having a problem, I need to import the data from `table2` to `table1`, I don't have the `code` field on `table2` and on the `table1` it is Auto Number, what I have to put `?HERE?` to my `code` be sequential?

```
INSERT INTO table1 ([code], [field1], [field2])
SELECT ?HERE?, [field1], [field2]
FROM [C:\MySystem\name.accdb].table2
```

Obs: It is MS Access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `code` is autonumber in table1 you don't need to include it and yes it will be sequential according to the order of `select`

```
INSERT INTO table1 ([field1], [field2])
SELECT  [field1], [field2]
FROM [C:\MySystem\name.accdb].table2
```